# NSFetchedResultsController keep reference to deallocated delegate controller in storyboard, causing crash

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, ios5, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uistoryboard

I have a simple UIViewTable, with a drill-down detail realized with a UINavigationController push segue in a storyboard.
It happen from time to time, that the table view controller seems to gets deallocated, while I am in the detail view, therefore I get the famous:

```
[MyViewController controllerWillChangeContent:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I explain better, I have an NSOperation queue which load my data asynchronously, and fill the table as soon as it just finished. The data are correctly retrieved and the table filled.
For the detail view, I am clicking on a cell and passing the NSManagedObjectID to the destination controller in prepareForSegue method. Very randomly when I made a change to the detail view the fetched controller loose its delegate, or as it seems, the delegate itself which is the controller gets deallocated. Causing a crash.

The fetched results controller is declared as a property:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
```

Then this is how everything is working starting from viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadDataAsynchronously];
}

-(void)loadDataAsynchronously {

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                            selector:@selector(loadData)
                                                                              object:nil];

    [queue addOperation:operation];
}


-(void)loadData {

    NSFetchRequest *findAllEntities = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [findAllEntities setEntity:ENTITY_DESC];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created" ascending:YES];
    [findAllEntities setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [findAllEntities setFetchBatchSize:20];

    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"MyCache"];
    if(self.fetchedResultsController==nil) {
        self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
                                            initWithFetchRequest:findAllPlants
                                            managedObjectContext:MOC
                                            sectionNameKeyPath:nil 
                                            cacheName:@"MyCache"];

        self.fetchedResultsController.delegate=self;
    }
    NSError *error=nil;
    if (![FRC performFetch:&error]) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    [self.dataTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];    

}
```

this code works, and most of the time also works within the detail view which is called as a segue like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    IP2SegueIdentifier segueIdentifier = [IP2Factory segueSolver:[segue identifier]];  
    MyDestinationViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [TV indexPathForSelectedRow];
    dvc.entityID=[[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath] objectID];

}
```

and the destination controller correctly get the entity id and reconstruct the object by asking the context. 
Then, when I am in the detail view controller, I can make change to the entity, and when I go back to the navigation hierarchy I do a context save.
It is at this point that the application crashes, just right at context save. Not so often, but from time to time.
Because the fetched results controller recognize the change and submitted to its delegate which is already deallocated.

I have few doubts at this point, I am using iOS 5 and ARC so the compiler is supposed to have (almost) full control over release and dealloc methods. And I am also using a storyboard with a simple navigation hierarchy, which should guarantee that the whole previous view controllers chain gets retained.

I also run the profiler for memory leak/zombies analysis, but wasn't able to spot anything wrong, on the contrary I was happy the all the objects management were fine.

I have not many guess at this point, so please feel free to point out something I could have forgotten to check, or something you see wrong in my code.

thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, a note about ARC. While ARC provides auto-zeroing `weak` pointers, it does not make `assign` pointers auto-zeroing. `NSFetchResultsController` uses an `assign` property for its delegate (see `NSFetchedResultsController.h`):

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id< NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate > delegate;
```

It is still your responsibility to clear yourself as the delegate before you deallocate. You typically do this in `dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  _fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
}
```

You may also want to get rid of your `fetchedResultsController` in `viewWillDisappear:` (including removing yourself as the delegate). Typically you do not want fetch requests to stay around when you are offscreen. (If you do, you probably should manage the fetch in a model object rather than in a view controller, since a view controller can go away anytime its view is offscreen.)

Your `loadData` is strange in that it creates a `findAllEntities`, but actually uses `findAllPlants`. Was this a typo or a bug? If there is a separate `findAllPlants` fetch request in an ivar, this could also be a cause of your problems.

Comment: _(If you do, you probably should manage the fetch in a model object rather than in a view controller, since a view controller can go away anytime its view is offscreen.)_ isn't the fetched results controller typically a property of the view controller that is displaying the results of the fetch? Can you give an example of the sort of structure you are talking about, it sounds interesting.

Comment: In most cases it is best to keep the fetch controller on a 1:1 basis with view controllers, and I'm not recommending diverging from that. But you should never expect the fetch controller to do anything (or even exist) while you're offscreen. If you need it to, you should move it (or more likely the fetch itself) into a model controller rather than a view controller. But you're correct, this is not a normal situation, and in most cases is probably not even a good situation.

Comment: It seems to be working, with your suggestion about 'delegate'. One thing that it's not clear, why the previous controller in hierarchy got dealloc ? Shouldn't the UINavigationController keep it alive and safe in an NSArray ?

Comment: Actually that's a really good question. You shouldn't (prior to storyboards) get deallocated as long as you're in the navigation controller's `viewControllers`, but you may get `viewDidUnload`. But with storyboards and segues, the behavior could be different, since the system can reload you from the storyboard. I haven't dug deeply into the memory management of view controllers within storyboards.

Comment: After few months, I agree with keeping fetched controller off when view is offscreen. However, what are the alternatives for update the table view, when an entity is added in other controller, I cannot find other way then refetch the query (reload table is not enough). Do you have any good advice for that ?

Comment: You should refetch the query. Is that problematic?

Comment: Is this comment relevant in iOS 6+? "You may also want to get rid of your fetchedResultsController in viewWillDisappear: (including removing yourself as the delegate). Typically you do not want fetch requests to stay around when you are offscreen. (If you do, you probably should manage the fetch in a model object rather than in a view controller, since a view controller can go away anytime its view is offscreen.)"

`viewDidUnload` is deprecated and per the documentation "In iOS 6 and later, clearing references to views and other objects in your view controller is unnecessary."

Comment: viewDidUnload is gone, but the advice is unchanged. As you noted, I am recommending `viewWillDisappear:`, which is the correct place to do it.